# Asserting that a C# type defines an operator

Tags: c#, .net

My question is simple.  I need to be able to evaluate a tree of string values, with labeled types.  I have found a method that looks something like this for evaluating those strings.

```
private static ITypeNode _evaluateExpr(ExprNode node)
{
    switch (node.Name)
    {
        case "ChangeSign":
            {
            var val = _convertToCSharpType(node.Type, ((ValueNode)node.Nodes[0]).Value);

            string newVal = "";
            if (val is int)
                 newVal = (-(int)val).ToString();
            else if (val is long)
                 newVal = (-(long)val).ToString();
            else if (val is float)
                 newVal = (-(float)val).ToString();
            else if (val is double)
                 newVal = (-(double)val).ToString();

            return new ValueNode(newVal, node.Type);
            }
      }
}
```

The convertToCSharpType method returns an object type based on the provided node. (this object type contains an underlying type that the converted type)
There are most branches on that switch, i just did not add them.

As for the two other classes:

```
class ExprNode : TreeNode, ITypeNode
{
    public string Name { get; }
    public IDataType Type { get; set; }

    public ExprNode(string name, IDataType type)
    {
        Name = name;
        Type = type;
        Nodes = new List<ITypeNode>();
    }

    public ExprNode(string name, IDataType type, List<ITypeNode> nodes)
    {
        Name = name;
        Type = type;
        Nodes = nodes;
    }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return $"{Name}:[{string.Join(", ", Nodes.Select(x => x.ToString()))}]";
    }
}

// stores literal values
class ValueNode : ITypeNode
{
    public string Name { get; }
    public IDataType Type { get; set; }

public string Value;

    public ValueNode(string name, IDataType type)
    {
        Name = name;
        Type = type;
    }

    public ValueNode(string name, IDataType type, string value)
    {
        Name = name;
        Type = type;
        Value = value;
    }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return $"Value({Name}, {Type}, {Value})";
    }
}
```

ITypeNode is just an interface that defines certain methods that all nodes of must have and TreeNode simply indicates that these classes have sub nodes. (it gives them a `List<ITypeNode> Nodes` property)

My question is this, is there a way I can avoid having an if-tree of every single operator I need to evaluate for.  Is there someone that a method can return multiple types without explicitly having it provided?  Or is there someway to assert that a type defines certain operators?  As in,

```
(obj as interface { operator+ }) + (obj2 as interface { operator+ })
```

Is something in that vein possible?

Please let me know if you need more context.  Thanks!

Comment: This work looks like it would greatly benefit from the use of [*expression trees.*](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/expression-trees/)

Comment: See also [here](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/wiki/Scripting-API-Samples).

Comment: and [here](http://www.csscript.net/).

Comment: _" is there someway to assert that a type defines certain operators?"_ - [How to get defined operators for a type in .net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1412757/how-to-get-defined-operators-for-a-type-in-net)

Comment: Thank you stuartd.  That is what i needed.