# Is there a way to get all defined operators on any type?

Tags: c#, .net, types, operator-overloading

Quick disclaimer: I realize a similar question has already been asked here [How to get defined operators for a type in .net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1412757/how-to-get-defined-operators-for-a-type-in-net), but since this question does not answer the question asked here as this question expands upon the one mentioned above, an answer to this question would be appreciated.

I would like to obtain a list of all operators that can de applied to a type. To simplify the code snippets, I will only print the operators in the console though.
For example, `DateTime` defines a `+`, two `-` operators, and one operator for each inequality `<`, `<=`, etc. and the `==` operators. I can get a comprehensive list of all these operators by using the following code:

```cs
foreach (var method in typeof(DateTime).GetMethods())
{
    if (method.IsSpecialName)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(method.Name);
    }
}
```

which prints:

```
get_UtcNow
op_Addition
op_Subtraction
op_Subtraction
op_Equality
op_Inequality
op_LessThan
op_LessThanOrEqual
op_GreaterThan
op_GreaterThanOrEqual
get_Date
...
```

where every method beginning with op_ is the corresponding operator.

However when applying this code to `int` or any other primitive type, the list is either incomprehensive or even empty.
When applied to `typeof(int)` for example, there are no methods with special name and as such no operators, which is obviously wrong.

I *think* this is because `DateTime` uses operator overloading while `int` does not and as such does not define the methods 'op_Addition', etc. The `-` operator for example on `int` can be pretty much directly translated to the `sub` instruction in assembly.

If I wanted to get all operators for `int` anyways now, I could obviously just define a list of all operators defined on `int` and any other type, but since there are quite a few types, for which you cannot get all operators using the above method, like `string`, `float`, `Int64`, etc. I don't think this is a good approach.
Alternatively, you can try to convert them to `dynamic` and just apply an operator then, but since this will throw an exception, if the operator is not defined, and seems very unelegant to me, I would still like to try and find a better way of doing this.

```cs
TryMultiply<float, string>(5.0f, "abc", out var a);


bool TryMultiply<TA, TB>(TA a, TB b, out object result)
{
    try
    {
        dynamic dA = (dynamic)a;
        dynamic dB = (dynamic)b;
        result = dA * dB;
        return true;
    }
    catch (RuntimeBinderException e)
    {
        result = default;
        return false;
    }
}
```

And even then, you only know, that the `*` operator is not defined for `float` and `string`. But you cannot make a statement about any other types, which renders this approach basically useless.

Comment: Operators for primitive types are defined by the compiler. There's nothing in the type system to discover. For example, multiplying two `int`s is a `mul` instruction, which uses the top two values from the evaluation stack. There's no `op_*` method to call.

Comment: @madreflection I knew that multiplying two ```int```s is a ```mul``` instruction, but I would have thought, that there is a way to get all operators on those types anyways.

Comment: That my point, though... there's no way *because* it's a native instruction and not a static method. Again, nothing to discover in the type system.

Comment: @madreflection ok, thanks for the answer. It's sad to hear, this isn't possible, but it's good to know.

Comment: At least in .NET 6, Int32 does define all these operators (but they are implemented throw explicit interface implementation). See https://sharplab.io/#v2:C4LgTgrgdgPgAgBgARwIwDoAyBLKBHAbgFgAoUgNwEMwldgAVATwAcBTJAXiWBdYHsAZgAo6ASmIkBfMK0oBjABZCqNALa0oGhr3QBxVsACyBhXwAmAZyFp0AJVYCANqznBsfKOgBCuM7gDmAGKOlP4W6ADKwJRucvAY9k4ubh7evgHBoeEAch4AChAARo7YcqLoAOoKrDJC6hwAfEiq6NmUqqzoAMIe0bhWAER8zAD6A6ITpEjTKBhoAJx1re2s4kA=