# How to convert a unknown type (object) using conversion operators?

Tags: c#

I have a few types that are basically string representations with implicit conversion operators from and to string.

With JSON.NET they serialize automatically, but I am migrating to System.Text.Json at the moment. Instead of writing a converter for all these types, I would like to have a generic solution.

I tried this approach:

```
public sealed class TypeConverterJsonConverter<T> : JsonConverter<T>
{
    private readonly TypeConverter typeConverter = TypeDescriptor.GetConverter(typeof(T));

    public override bool CanConvert(Type typeToConvert)
    {
        return base.CanConvert(typeToConvert);
    }

    public override T? Read(ref Utf8JsonReader reader, Type typeToConvert, JsonSerializerOptions options)
    {
        return (T)typeConverter.ConvertFromInvariantString(text!)!;
    }
}
```

It works, but only if the type has a type converter with the `TypeConverterAttribute`, otherwise a default converter is returned. This default converter does not invoke the conversion operators.

I am looking for the .NET way to convert a string to an object when this class has an implicit conversion operator. Without reflection if possible.

So if I have this class

```
class Foo {
   public Foo(string value) {}

   public static implicit operator Foo(string value)
   {
       return new Foo(value);
   }
}
```

How can I implement method `Convert`?

```
var result = Convert<Foo>("hello world");
```

I had a look to the JSON.NET Code, but I cannot find the correct place. How can I convert a string to a object using the correct conversion operator?

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include a [mcve] which shows what you are trying to do and what the problem is.

Comment: Okay, I have added the example.-

Comment: Not a duplicate question, but I'd expect this to help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1412757